# onClick Listener on DrawerLayout Does Not Launch Toast

Tags: java, android, android-intent, navigation-drawer, arrays

I'm attempting to implement a toast depending on the item clicked in a DrawerLayout - however I cannot seem to get the toasts to appear no matter what I do. I'm not sure exactly what I did wrong: any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);
            drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
            drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
            drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
            drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
            drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                            GravityCompat.START); 


    /* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

     private void selectItem(int position) {



                if ( position == 1 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if ( position == 2 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


            private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                            Log.d("pk", "onItemClick");
                            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the
                            // drawer
                            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                            drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                            setTitle("......");

                            String text = "menu click... should be implemented";
                            // Toast.makeText(Home.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

                    }

            }
```

Comment: so what's wrong? switch case not working?

Comment: maybe String clickedOn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items)[position]

Comment: Yes - the switch case is not working.

Comment: Entreco or Raghunandan can you provide an answer? I'll gladly accept if you can help get this resolved (I'm under a serious deadline at this point)

Comment: why do you put intents in the drawer? it's supposed to switch between fragments within the current activity, and not to start new activities... 

anyway, can you please remove code that is not relevant to the problem?

Comment: I changed them to toasts for simplicity sake and removed the additional code as requested

Comment: Any ideas? I'm stumped. : )

Comment: you have 2 classes called "DrawerItemClickListener " on the same file? anyway, have you tried to debug , put a breakpoint and see if it gets there? i don't see why it shouldn't work. try to make a new project with just a listview and use the same code. does it work well there? which library of menuDrawer do you use? i suggest using this one: http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/ . it has plenty of features. it also has a sample code that look very similar to what you do.

Comment: I removed the extra DrawerItemClickListener - I did notice that when I click anything on the menu - it appears to launch whatever is behind it  (there are youtube thumbnails behind it - it simply launches the video as if i clicked it instead of the drawer item overlaid on top of it)

Comment: I added a breakpoint at Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Clicked", and it is never reached when clicking anything in the drawerLayout http://pastebin.com/BviCdg1i

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something very much like this.  I was using Fragments but the concept is very much the same.

First I created the DrawerLayout:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

// read in the menu items form the string array
    String[] menuList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_menu);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuList));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Then I define the `DrawerItemClickListener`:

```
/* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

Finally I implement the `selectItem` method:

```
    private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;

    if ( position == 1 )
    {
        fragment = new CalendarFrag();
    }
    else if ( position == 2 )
    {
        fragment = new ContactsFrag();
    }
    else
    {
        fragment = new EmailListFragment();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

You could easily replace the Fragments with Activities, and the `beginTransation` with a `startActivity`.

Comment: I don't see where you call beginTransation

Comment: near the bottom:  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

Comment: Thanks! I implemented your method - and for simplicity sake I replaced the intents with a Toast however I never see the toast when clicking any of the items (I thought I copied your method perfectly - but I seem to have done something wrong) http://pastebin.com/CFGfRFzj

Comment: I updated my source above to match your suggestion but it still doesn't work