# Unable to Set Text Size Using FlowTextView

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-library

I found a library which allows an app to wrap text around an image - however once implemented it changed the size of my text - how can the text size be increase when using this library?

`android:textSize=` has no impact on the text size.

Neither does:

```
FlowTextView titleTv = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
((FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTv)).setTextSize(20);
```

https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/

**Example:**

```
<com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the short term a call to invalidate will probably get it working:

```
FlowTextView titleTv = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
titleTv.setTextSize(20);
titleTv.invalidate();
```

However, I suspect you are using the JAR file right? It is quite out of date so I would recommend checking the source code out and using it as an android library project - setTextSize() should work properly then without needing a call to invalidate() (plus various other bug fixes etc).

Also - I never added the ability to set the text size via XML - wouldn't be too hard to add this though.

Comment: I'm having a few other issues with this build as well... mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913058/android-xml-layout-parameters-do-not-function-as-expected

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911739/adding-a-textview-to-drag-and-drop-interface-android-java

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code of `android-flowtextview` and they have the text size **hardcoded** (check line 131 **[here](https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/source/browse/trunk/src/com/pagesuite/flowtext/FlowTextView.java)**). You have to change their source code or use the public method `setTextSize(int)`.

Also, **[this link](https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/issues/detail?id=7)** might help you, as seems that someone already did something as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/source/browse/trunk/src/com/pagesuite/flowtext/FlowTextView.java

There's a 'setTextSize(int)' method that should do exactly what you're looking for.

If you want to set it from XML, it's a little more involved. Since FlowTextView's constructors ignore the AttributeSet that gets passed in, you'll have to code this yourself. Follow guides like this: http://kotikan.com/blog/posts/2012/09/android-attributes to figure out how to add custom attributes to your views.